# Zoom in/out how do I keep the aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css, aspect-ratio

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4jmY2/4/

If you Zoom in/out (ctrl +/-) you will see the elements move around, how can I keep the aspect ratio so the content will remain the same no matter what size?

HTML

```
<div class="check_box">        
    <div class="check">
        <div class="your_name">Your Name</div>
        <div class="bank_name">Your Bank Name</div>
        <div class="check_number_top">1001</div>
        <div class="your_address">Your Address</div>
        <div class="bank_address">Bank Address</div>
        <br />
        <div class="date">Date ________</div>
        <br />
        <div class="pay">Pay to the<br />Order of _______________________________ $________</div>
        <br />
        <div class="pay_line">_________________________________________ Dollars</div>
        <br />
        <div class="sign">_____________________</div>
        <br />
        <div class="check_number_bottom">&#9288;<strong>1001</strong>&#9288;</div>
        <div class="routing_number">&#9286;<strong>123456789</strong>&#9286;</div>
        <div class="account_number"><strong>987&nbsp;6543210</strong>&nbsp;&#9288;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.check_box {
    width: 300px;
}
.check {
    border: 2px solid #1A1B1B;
    background-color: #DFE5E5;
    height: 110px;
    font-size:80%;
    font-family: Georgia;    
    padding:0px;
    margin: 0px;    
}
.your_name {
    float:left;
    padding:0px 30px 0px 5px;
    font-size:105%;
}
.your_address {
    float:left;
    padding:0px 40px 0px 5px;
    font-size:85%;
}
.bank_name {
    float:left;
    padding:0px 30px 0px 5px;
    font-size:105%;
}
.bank_address {
    float:left;
    padding:0px 30px 0px 5px;
    font-size:85%;
}
.check_number_top {
    float:left;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 40px;
    font-size:105%;
}    
.date {
    float:left;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 220px;
    font-size:85%;
}
.pay {
    float:left;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 5px;
    font-size:85%;
}
.pay_line {
    float:left;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 5px;
    font-size:85%;
}
.sign {
    float:left;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 165px;
    font-size:85%;
}
.check_number_bottom {
    float:left;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 5px;
    font-size:85%;
    font-family:"Arial Narrow"; /* need to change the font's of the numbers */
}
.routing_number {
    float:left;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 5px;
    font-size:85%;
    font-family:"Arial Narrow"; /* need to change the font's of the numbers */
}    
.account_number {
    float:left;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;
    font-size:85%;
    font-family:"Arial Narrow"; /* need to change the font's of the numbers */
}
.routing_number_tip {
    float:left;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;
    font-size:85%;
    color:#1F4CA5;
}
.account_number_tip {
    float:left;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;
    font-size:85%;
    color:#1F4CA5;
}
```

Comment: What is it supposed to look like? I have a feeling this screenshot of your unchanged jsFiddle isn't right: http://i.imgur.com/wrEOS.png *(100% zoom, Chrome, Windows 7)*

Comment: http://imgur.com/updXw this is what it looks like to me

Comment: Just to let you know: if this isn't solved in a couple of hours, I'm going to look at it again.

Comment: I forgot to look again after I wrote that comment, sorry. I'll write an answer soon. It looks like it will take a fair few changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I finally had a go at doing this. I had to do it from scratch, and it took a while.

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/uuwtL/)

It looks like this for me:

[image]

- Tested in IE7/8 plus recent versions of Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera.
- You can zoom in!

If there's anything wrong or you have any questions, let me know.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="check_box">
    <div class="check">
        <span class="your_left"><em>Your Name</em><br />Your Address</span>
        <span class="your_mid"><em>Your Bank Name</em><br />Bank Address</span>
        <span class="your_right"><em>1001</em></span>

        <span class="date">Date<span></span></span>

        <span class="pay_to">Pay to the<br />Order of<span></span></span>
        <span class="dollar"><br />$<span></span></span>
        <span class="dollars"><span></span>Dollars</span>

        <span class="extraline"><span></span></span>

        <span class="numbers">
            <span>&#9288;<b>1001</b>&#9288;</span>
            <span>&#9286;<b>123456789</b>&#9286;</span>
            <span><b>987&nbsp;6543210</b>&nbsp;&#9288;</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.check_box {
    font: 10px/1.3 Georgia, serif;

    border: 2px solid #1a1b1b;
    background-color: #dfe5e5;

    width: 292px;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0
}
.check {
    position: relative;
    height: 102px
}
.check > span {
    position: absolute
}
.check em {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: normal
}
.date span, .pay_to span, .dollar span, .dollars span, .extraline span {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    zoom: 1 /* fix ie7 */
}

.your_left {
    top: 0; left: 0
}
.your_mid {
    top: 0; left: 95px; text-align: center
}
.your_right {
    top: 0; right: 0
}

.date {
    top: 28px; right: 0
}
.date span {
    padding-left: 50px;
    margin: 2px 0 0 3px
}

.pay_to {
    top: 35px; left: 0
}
.pay_to span {
    padding-left: 180px;
    margin-left: 3px
}

.dollar {
    top: 35px; right: 0; text-align: right
}
.dollar span {
    padding-left: 50px;
    margin-left: 3px
}

.dollars {
    top: 62px; left: 0
}
.dollars span {
    padding-left: 250px;
    margin-right: 3px
}

.extraline {
    top: 76px; right: 0
}
.extraline span {
    padding-left: 120px
}

.numbers {
    bottom: 0; left: 0
}
.numbers span {
    margin: 0 10px 0 0
}
```

Comment: one more follow up, wanted to know how to change the width: 292px; to something smaller to start off with. running media queries to adjust the size before rendering but if I change this size value the whole image just doesn't look right

Comment: If you want to have this relatively sized, I suggest you change all the dimensions into `em` values (which are relative). Here's a *start*: http://jsfiddle.net/uuwtL/4/ - you can change the `0.6em` value on `.check_box`, and all sizes will change.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that I understand your question. But when I zoom in, the text components scale up while the background "check" style does not.

It sounds like you want the check to scale up as well. If so, you might need to create em-driven div styles, which will scale with the browsers font selection.

Here's a good [article with several examples](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/liquid/).

Comment: so are you saying I should move to em instead of px or %? +1 for the link

Comment: I have been playing around with em and I still get the same results: http://jsfiddle.net/4jmY2/44/