# keep proportions of image when scrolling out (ctrl - ) css

Tags: css, zooming

I am having this issue at: http://bananabay.dejaloasi.com/ where when i zoom out the image of the slider get cuted and won't allow to see correctly. I've already read and try this [Zoom in/out how do I keep the aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395532/zoom-in-out-how-do-i-keep-the-aspect-ratio), applying the height auto on the img and both of max width and height. But still haven't got the expected results. Any help would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this css:

```
.tp-simpleresponsive .slotholder *, .tp-simpleresponsive img {
    width: auto !important;
}
```

This will get the image maintain proportion but on large screen image wont expand to cover entire screen & it shouldn't cuz it gets pixelated if stretched

Comment: thanks Imran, yeah now i see that image won't expand on larger screens, i was trying to figure out how could i make it flexible so it covers the whole div. I guess i will have to let the img lose some proportions to fill the whole area, i also try with media queries but i see that applying the style when less or even more resolution haven't help me. Any suggestions?

Comment: When you zoomout everything get smaller -- including the slider area but if you want the image to get small as well you will have to make sure its not expanding in full width -- I mean theoretically its not possible to keep the proportion yet make it get smaller cuz each time you zoom out image has to cover more width then height. Got my point?

Comment: yeah i think i got the point, so i should be like 90% or so? i mean can't be 100% right cuz it wouludn't be proportioned, i haven't try it out. But am on it right now

Comment: Hey Imran, really thanks i follow the idea and i could solve my issue, my solution was this: Where if you have a div container then a sub-div container and more deeper exist a img where you set the auto image height and set a max-height limit. [Link to the Source CSS](http://hastebin.com/egawolamoc.avrasm)

Comment: @GabouhSk8 Ok, I saw your site... the images are getting cutoff from the bottom try doing this: `.defaultimg{ width: auto !important; max-height: 567px !important; }` and remove the other styles you have on this class, on line number 3395. After that your entire image will be visible but you might want to adjust arrows.

Comment: thanks i that help me out, i just keep a different max height but i that was what i did.